# Get the XPath to each first element and count its sibling occurrences for any XML input

Tags: xml, xslt

i need to count every repeated elements in XML documents using xsl,the structure of xml is not known,So if my xml is as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <title>Hide your heart1</title>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
<catalog>
```

Expected output should be like this:

```
catalog.cd.count=2
catalog.cd[0].title.count=1
catalog.cd[0].artist.count=1
catalog.cd[0].country.count=1
catalog.cd[0].company.count=1
catalog.cd[0].price.count=1
catalog.cd[0].year.count=1
catalog.cd[1].title.count=2
catalog.cd[1].price.count=2
catalog.cd[1].year.count=2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using (1.0, 2.0, 3.0), and what processor?

Comment: Anyway, for the fun of it, I've added a solution for all three, works good for comparisons between the three standards :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't answer my question, but here goes anyway:

### XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="nm" select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[name() = $nm])">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
        <xsl:variable name="nm" select="name()" />
        <xsl:variable name="same" select="../*[name() = $nm]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = $nm]) + 1 " />
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:text>count = </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($same)" />
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or:

### XSLT 2.0 (-10 lines)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            if(preceding-sibling::*/name() = name()) 
            then () else ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
        <xsl:variable name="nm" select="name()" />
        <xsl:value-of separator="" select="name(),
            if(position() = last()) 
            then ('.count = ', count(../*[name() = $nm]), '&#xA;')
            else ('[', count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = $nm]) + 1, ']', '.')" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or:

### XSLT 3.0 (-20 lines)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0" expand-text="yes">

    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" />

    <xsl:template match="*[not(preceding-sibling::*/name() = name())]" >{        
            path()!replace(., '^/|Q\{\}|\[1\]$', '')!translate(., '/', '.')
            || '.count = ' || count(../*[name() = current()/name()]) || '&#xA;'
        }<xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of each of these is:

```
catalog.count = 1
catalog[1].cd.count = 2
catalog[1].cd[1].title.count = 1
catalog[1].cd[1].artist.count = 1
catalog[1].cd[1].country.count = 1
catalog[1].cd[1].company.count = 1
catalog[1].cd[1].price.count = 1
catalog[1].cd[1].year.count = 1
catalog[1].cd[2].title.count = 2
catalog[1].cd[2].price.count = 2
catalog[1].cd[2].year.count = 2
```

Comment: @RudramuniTP, thanks! Just added the XSLT 3.0 version. I liked the "assignment", in that it (1) shows the power of XSLT, (2) clearly shows the progression between the versions and (3) shows quite a few XSLT concept in those few lines.